# Framework 4, ASP.NET Web Site, IsNullOrWhiteSpace not defined

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a ASP.NET Web Page using Framework 4 and I just realized that `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` existed in Framework 4, I know I'm slow.  Anyway, I changed all my `IsNullOrEmpty` to `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, since I was having to, `if !String.IsNullOrEmpty then trim`, and check length, which was insain, but the only way to actually make sure it wasn't empty.  So I was quite happy to see this new method.   However, in my classes behind my aspx pages, I can use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`, but the other common classes that do not have pages, I get this error.

> Error 12 `string` does not contain a
>   definition for `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`

Same project, same namespace, not the same results..

Need answers, 
Mr Confused

Answer (score 1):

are your other common classes in a different project and if so look at properties and make sure it's set to .net 4.0.

Comment: The only difference between the two classes is the one that works has an ASPX page and the one that doesn't falls under the App_Data folder.  If I type, "String.", the intellisense pulls up the method, I can see it, but if I try to use it, it gives me this error.

Comment: app_data folder is use dfor database files and such. create another folder. I usually have my non-web code in a dll project but this article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetAppFolder.aspx has mdf files in app_data. I wonder if that has restrictions on it.

Comment: humm, well anytime I've ever created a common class, I get a dialog that says, it would like to put it in app_data.  I've always clicked yes, assuming MS wanted it there for a reason, but I'll try that.

Comment: ok, I don't know why I typed App_Data, I mean't app_code folder.  My head is so wrapped up into figuring out this issue, I'm starting to confuse myself.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the common class back to IsNullOrEmpty and when I did that, the aspx class pages now throw the same error.  So I guess the whole project can't use them.  I looked at my build and it says Framework 4 is the target, the intellisense pulls it up, but it can't compile if I use it.

Comment: ok cam eacross this. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464(vs.80).aspx says app_code was used for web site projects and doesn't really work in web application projects. I created an app_code folder and i couldn't access my code so came across that. Never used the folder structure before so was new to me.

Comment: Maybe, because this is an ASP.NET Web Site, not an ASP.NET Web Application?

Comment: I don't even know how to create a web site in VS 2010. all the options are for web application. Is this an upgraded project? If this is an application then looks like no more app_code folder. I can't get that to work at all. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: If you click on "New" in the menu, you will see "Project" or "Web Site".  I'm actually reattempting it as a Web Application to see if it makes a difference.   (Edit, it looks like it works fine as a Web Application, so I'll go that route, but still interested in why it doesn't for Web Site.)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're targeting the 4.0 version of the framework in the compilation of your aspx pages. Try putting an explicit compilation element in your web.config, under the system.web tag and see if it works:

```
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```